# A function on quaternion matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, matrix-calculus

Let $A$ be a positive-definite matrix over the rings of quaternions with size $n\times n$. Let $f$ be a function that $f(A)=r_{1}^{m_{1}}...r_{t}^{m_{t}}$ where $r_i$'s are eigenvalues of $A$ and $ m_{i} $'s are algebraic multiplicities of $r_i$'s.

Is this true, $f(AB)=f(A)f(B)?

Comment: I think that $f$ gives the determinant, if so, the multiplicative property follows, right? Even if the field is the quaternions?

Comment: And a matrix of quaternions always has eigenvalues, and these eigenvalues commute (so that the product you wrote as definition of $f$ does not depend on the ordering of the eigenvalues)?

Comment: Yes. Since $A$ is positive definite, so the eigenvalues are real positive numbers.

Comment: Is there a reference for this?

Comment: I believe the proof is the same as for complex hermitian matrices, except that the 'conjugate' in the 'conjugate transpose' is now the quaternionic cojugate $a + bi + cj + dk \mapsto a - bi - cj - dk$. It has the very nice property that $(xy)* = y^*x^*$ and that $x*x = xx^* \in \mathbb{R}$ where the latter is viewed as a subfield of $\mathbb{H}$.

Comment: What I do not find immediately obvious is that the determinant (as defined in @PaulAljabar 's comment) is still a ring homomorphism from $Mat(n, \mathbb{H})$ to $\mathbb{H}$. If it is I would be interested in more general question of how many of the equivalent definition of determinant over a field are still equivalent over a skew field.

Comment: Complex hermitian matrices have commuting entries, and that tends to be important...

Comment: There is no such thing as a determinant with the usual properties for matrices over a noncommutative ring. The closest one gets is the so called Dieudonné determinant, which is not quite the same thing as the determinant.ç